# Laravel - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel

I go this error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

I'm using in controller:

```
$data = '{"pr":{"code":"1"},"ac":[[{"icon":"web","action":"link","url":"asd"}]]}'
$newData = json_decode($data);
```

And i send it to the view as array: 'data' => $newData
And when i try to use $data into the view, it give me that error

Tried already to use $data->ac OR $data['ac'] but still the same...
Some help, please?

Comment: Can you add the code of the view?

Comment: {{ $data }} => That's all.

Comment: json_decode returns an object by default. use `$newData = json_decode($data,TRUE);` for an array

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When you use a blade echo `{{ $data }}` it will automatically escape the output. It can only escape strings. In your data `$data->ac` is an array and `$data` is an object, neither of which can be echoed as is. You need to be more specific of how the data should be outputted. What exactly that looks like entirely depends on what you're trying to accomplish. For example to display the link you would need to do `{{ $data->ac[0][0]['url'] }}` (not sure why you have two nested arrays but I'm just following your data structure).

```
@foreach($data->ac['0'] as $link)
    <a href="{{ $link['url'] }}">This is a link</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I had this because `$errors->get()` was returning an array. Switching to `$errors->first()` fixed this.

Answer (score 19):

if you real intention is to send the full array from the html to the controller, you can use the following code:

from the blade.php:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="quotation" value="{{ json_encode($quotation,TRUE)}}">
```

in controller

```
    public function Get(Request $req) {

    $quotation = array('quotation' => json_decode($req->quotation));

    //or
    
    return view('quotation')->with('quotation',json_decode($req->quotation))


}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use `serialize`

```
<input type="hidden" name="quotation[]" value="{{serialize($quotation)}}">
```

But best way in this case use the `json_encode` method in your blade and `json_decode` in controller.

Answer (score 4):

This is the proper way to access data in laravel :

```php
@foreach($data-> ac as $link) 

   {{$link->url}}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use in your collection the `json_encode()`.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

```
public static function getTeamMemberInto($user_id){
    
    $team = DB::table('members_team')
                ->join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'members_team.teams_id')
                ->join('employees', 'employees.id', '=', 'teams.leader_employees_id')
                ->where('members_team.employees_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->select('*')->first();
    // dd($team);
    if($team){
        return json_encode($team, true);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
                        
}
```