# Convert a Laravel Collection/Array to a Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, laravel

I would like to assign an array from Laravel to a JavaScript array. I have gotten the array from my *`AppServiceProvider`* and json_decoded it like:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
   $users = Users::all();
   $view->with(compact(users );
}
```

I then access my $usersArray from my javascript file like:

```
  var dataSet = JSON.parse({!!$users !!});
```

I am however getting the following error;

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Check the actual output in the page. What does the JS code look like? Debug it from there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php array to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am only getting the Laravel error output

Comment: In which case case you should Google the error. It leads to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43217872/519413

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated my question.

Comment: That new error is because you're calling `JSON.parse()` on a value which is not JSON formatted. Now you need to check the actual output in the page to debug the problem as my first comment mentioned.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Okay. Currently, in the console log, I am seeing jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
That is the only Javacript output I can see

Comment: That's the error in the console. I mean that you actually need to view the source of the page to read the JS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're encoding it in the server side, you need to decode it in the client side like:

```
$chequesArray = Users::all()->toJson();

var dataSet = JSON.parse({!!json_encode($chequesArray)!!});
```

Or also Using "base64_encode" to conserve the json format like:

```
$chequesArray = base64_encode(Users::all()->toJson());

var dataSet = JSON.parse(atob('{{$chequesArray}}');
```

The main difference comes from the use of `{{ }}` vs `{!! !!}`, the first one escapes the special chars so it will turn the quotes `""` to `&quot;` then the JS will be unable to parse the string (that why we can use `base64_encode``to conserve the format), the second one will conserve the format and allow the quotes what gives the JS part the ability to parse it simply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am now getting the error "jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2 SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2"

Comment: You're welcome, That happens because "$users" isn't an array it's a collection.

Comment: Okay. Kindlyy explain how I can convert it from an collection to an array

Comment: convert like this $users->toArray();

Comment: I get the Laravel error "Array to string conversion" when I do var dataSet = JSON.parse({!! $users->toArray !!});

Comment: I'd suggest the use of base64 to conserve the format of your JSON, check my update.

Comment: Thank you very much Zakaria. It works! Please please explain what just happened

Comment: You're welcome brother, I was playing with for a while, you could see my updated answer with too working versions.

Comment: The main difference comes from the use of "{{ }}" vs "{!! !!}", the first one escape the special chars so it will turn the quotes `""` to `&quot;` then the JS will be unable to parse it, the second one will conserve the format and allow the quotes.

Comment: Ok. Noted. Thanks again Zakaria

Answer (score -2):

```
var dataSet = @php $chequesArray @endphp;
```