# Laravel variable not recognised in section script

Tags: javascript, laravel

My page.blade.php has several sections and I am using laravel variable $companies which works fine in the content section but not in the js scripts section.  What is wrong?

```
@extends ('layout.master')

@section ('styles')
   ...
@endsection

@section ('content')
@foreach ($companies as $company)
  using {{ $company->company }} works fine here
@endforeach

@section ('scripts')
<script>
  ...
@foreach ($companies as $company) returns error "Undefined variable: companies (View: /Users/paul/WebSites/FairTrade/resources/views/page.blade.php)"
  using {{ $company->company }} 
@endforeach
  ...
</script>
```

Thank you for helping...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Laravel Collection/Array to a Javascript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257436/convert-a-laravel-collection-array-to-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing (laravel) Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326699/passing-laravel-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Close your `@section ('content')` first. You might want to consider using [Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks)