# Laravel - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in Form Array

Tags: jquery, laravel

Currently, I am using Laravel-5.8 to develop a web application. In the project, I tried to dynamically add input fields using select option change based on condition.

**Controller**

```
    public $rating_points = [
    "1" => "Three-Star-Rating",
    "2" => "Four-Star-Rating",
    "3" => "Five-Star-Rating",
    "4" => "Six-Star-Rating",
    "5" => "Seven-Star-Rating",
];

public function create()
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('rating_create'), 403);
    return view('appraisal.ratings.create')->with('rating_points', $this->rating_points);
}

public function store(StoreRatingRequest $request)
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('rating_create'), 403);

    $rating = AppraisalRating::create([
        'rating_point'               => $request->rating_point,
        'rating_type'               => $request->rating_type,
        'rating_value'              => $request->rating_value,
        'rating_description'        => $request->rating_description,
        'company_id'                => Auth::user()->company_id,
        'created_by'                => Auth::user()->id,
        'created_at'                => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'is_active'                 => 1,
    ]);
    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Rating is created successfully');
    return redirect()->route('appraisal.ratings.index');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('rating_edit'), 403);
    $rating = AppraisalRating::where('id', $id)->first();       
    return view('appraisal.ratings.edit')->with('rating', $rating)->with('rating_types', $this->rating_types);
}

public function update(UpdateRatingRequest $request, $id)
{

    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('rating_edit'), 403);

    $rating = AppraisalRating::find($id);                            
    $rating->rating_point                 = $request->rating_point;
    $rating->rating_type                 = $request->rating_type;
    $rating->rating_value                = $request->rating_value;
    $rating->rating_description          = $request->rating_description;
    $rating->company_id                  = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $rating->updated_by                  = Auth::user()->id;
    $rating->updated_at                  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $rating->is_active                   = 1;
    $rating->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Rating is updated successfully');
    return redirect()->route('appraisal.ratings.index');
}
```

**view**

```html
    <div class="card-body">
       <form  action="{{route('appraisal.ratings.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           {{csrf_field()}}
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="rating-point" class="col-4 col-form-label"> Rating Point<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 controls">
                                            <select id='rating-point' class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Choose Rating Value" tabindex="1" name="rating_point[]">
                                                <option value="">Select Rating Point</option>
                                                @foreach($rating_points as $k => $rating_point)
                                                    <option value="{{$k}}" @if(old("rating_point") == "$k") selected @endif>{{$rating_point}}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>

                        <div class="row" id="rating-data"></div>
                    </div>
          
            <div id="rating-button" style="display: none;">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.ratings.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> 
    @endsection

    @section('javascript')
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
    $('#rating-point').on('change', function() {
     $('#rating-data').html('');

      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        var numInputs = '3';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         }           
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '2')
      {
        var numInputs = '4';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         } 
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '3')
      {
        var numInputs = '5';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         } 
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '4')
      {
        var numInputs = '6';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         } 
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '5')
      {
        var numInputs = '7';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         } 
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#rating-button").hide();
      }
     });
    });
   </script>

   @stop
```

[image: rating_point]

The problem is that when I clicked on submit button I expected it to save in the database, but I got this error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hris\resources\views\appraisal\ratings\create.blade.php)

How do I resolve this issue?

Secondly, I don't know if I have written the controller actions for save and update appropriately.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217872/laravel-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this because you use

name="rating_point[]"

In your select HTML

This means that your controller does receive an ARRAY
and expects a scalar value, like a string.

*Secondly, I don't know if I have written the controller actions for save and update appropriately.*

I've could imagine many improvements, but it don't think this is the place to do code reviews.

Comment: Where and how can you help me out?

Comment: The problem is still there

Comment: You probably mess up arrays and single values the same way for other properties.

This probably gives you a line number in your view, dump it with var_dump or dd, maybe before even passing it to the view. And probably you'll say it might contain something you didn't expect. (If your view is huge, you might lookup the compiled view, to find the exact line, if it doesn't make sense at once)