# Print specific data to blade view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can't find how to print data on the blade.view. I have a list of "customers" on overview.blade.php, and I have a button that redirects to their profile based on their "nCustomerID" (which is blade.view for me).

When I use the dump function on blade.view page does show the correct data for each " customer" I have in my database, but I don't know how to print it on the blade.view. Would love to get some documentation or explanation to read along on this.

Controller:

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $oCustomer = Customer::getCustomer($id);
        return view('Customers.view', ['nCustomerID' => $id]);
    }
```

Comment: why are you passing `$id` to view? you should pass `$oCustomer` then print it on view

Comment: @Moshiur I'm kinda new to laravel and this is the way I figured out it worked (not as it's suppose to as it seems). I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Compact()` methods to show data in Laravel `blade` view.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $oCustomer = Customer::getCustomer($id);
    return view('Customers.view',compact('oCustomer');
}
```

In view try this way.

```
 /*if oCustomer is a collection */
 @foreach($oCustomer as $customer)
     {{$customer->name}}
 @endforeach

 /* if oCustomer is a single object*/
 {{$oCustomer->name}} or {{$oCustomer[0]->name}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a bit. Any chance you could help me the other data (such as name)? or give me a push in the right direction? @Gabrielle-M

Answer (score 1):

use below code to print id

```
{{ $nCustomerID }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **compact()** in  controller to pass a variable or data into blade file.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $oCustomer = Customer::getCustomer($id);
    return view('Customers.view', compact(['oCustomer','id]));
}
```

In blade

```
{{$oCustomer}}
{{$id}}
```

For Details
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade

Comment: Alright, I tried this but now I get this error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: Path\view.blade.php). Any way I could print as object instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217872/laravel-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given follow this

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass variables using array in controller

```
public function show($id)
{
   $oCustomer = Customer::getCustomer($id);
   return view('Customers.view',['data'=>$oCustomer]);
}
```

and in you view file

```
{{$data}}
```