# Laravel Auth Return

Tags: laravel

I created a function in users model to return permission and return as obj. but when i type {{ Auth::user()->permission()->outlineAgreements }} it said "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given". How can i fix it ?

PS: inside test value is an array

```
"{"outlineAgreements":["view"],"purchaseOrder":["view"],"pwra":["view","create","update","delete"]}"
```

```
public function permission()
{
    $permissions = auth()->user()->getAllPermissions()->pluck('name');

    foreach ($permissions as $key => $value) {
        $module          = last(explode(" ", $value));
        $action          = current(explode(" ", $value));
        $result[$module] = $result[$module] ?? [];
        array_push($result[$module], $action);
    }

    return json_decode(json_encode($result));
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to output?

Comment: i wanna type "Auth::user()->permission()->outlineAgreements" can be output and array which is ['view', 'update', delete]

Comment: is this your error .? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217872/laravel-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given

Answer (score 0):

Php is complaining about an object print. It expects that the data you are instructing it to print is a `string`.

Use `dd` to print out the return of the permissions method for debugging. This way you can see more clearly what data you are about to print out.

```
{{ dd(Auth::user()->permission()) }}
```

```
{{ dd(Auth::user()->permission()->outlineAgreements) }}
```

If your first box represents that payload data, and you need to access and print all `outlineAgreements` permissions, and it is an array, you can use `implode`:

```
{{ implode(', ', Auth::user()->permission()->outlineAgreements) }}
```

You can loop through that array too:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->permission()->outlineAgreements as $permission)
    {{ $permission }} 
@endforeach
```

Hope it helped!