# Pass paginated data to alpine?

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I get my model

```
$users = User::all();
```

Pass to my view:

```
return view('pages.user.index')
        ->with('users', $users);
```

But now I want to pass into alpine:

```
<div x-data="{ items: {{ $users }} }">
```

That all works!

But if I do:

```
$users = User::paginate(20);
```

Then:

```
<div x-data="{ items: {{ $users->items() }} }">
```

I get:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

How can I pass a paginated set of data into alpine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217872/laravel-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return view('pages.user.index')
        ->with('users', $users->toJson());
```

```
<div x-data="{{ $users }}">
  <template x-for="user in data">
    <div x-text="user.name"></div>
  </template>
</div>
```