# Laravel Blade must be of type string, array given

Tags: laravel, database

I learning `Laravel` and have a recursive table that I need to loop through to get the `null` values as I need to then get the id's that they are linked to in order show the articles.

How can I loop through this in my blade template?

Blade view is returning... `htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given`

**Blade Template**

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
       {{$category}}
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
$categories = array();
    $parentCategories = Category::where('parent_id', null)->get();

    foreach($parentCategories as $parentCategory){
            $categories[] = Category::where('parent_id',$parentCategory->id)->with('articles')->get();
    };

    return view('marketplace.categories.index', [
        'categories' => $categories
 ]);
```

**Database Table**

[image]

Comment: In your blade file, `$categories` is an array and you're trying to `echo` it (`{{$category}}`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217872/laravel-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given)

Answer (score 2):

`get()` returns a collection of categories, so you probably wanted to do a loop in a loop. Since there are multiple categories with the same `parent_id`.

```
@foreach ($categories as $parentCategories)
    @foreach($parentCategories as $parentCategory)
        {{ $parentCategory->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

In controller try to change get to first,
change:

```
 foreach($parentCategories as $parentCategory){
        $categories[] = Category::where('parent_id',$parentCategory->id)->with('articles')->get();
};
```

to

```
 foreach($parentCategories as $parentCategory){
        $categories[] = Category::where('parent_id',$parentCategory->id)->with('articles')->first();
};
```

also in blade you should point to field name  as an example:

```
 @foreach ($categories as $category)
       {{$category->title}}
    @endforeach
```